# Import symbols from an existing binary in a linker script

Tags: linker, ld, linker-scripts

I am creating a binary for a microprocessor with flash and ram. The regular build process uses a linker script to declare where different sections should go and also exports parameters to the code, like which part of the ram can be used for heap.

For better development and updatability I want to add a custom bootloader at the beginning of the binary. However this leads to the need to add "magic constants" to the linker script of the main binary. E.g. the binary cannot start at the beginning of the flash anymore, but only a few kilobytes later, depending on the codesize of the bootloader. Additionally I want to reference some flash regions of the bootloader from the main binary.

As a primitive, I would like to be able to load symbols from an existing (.elf-)binary for usage in a linker script without including any payload data from the other binary, but that does not seem to be possible.

So after linking I would like to have 2 binaries:

- `bootloader.elf` (uses flash 0x10000000 - 0x1004a000)
- `application.elf` (uses flash 0x1004a000 - 0x10080000 and references other symbols in `bootloader.elf`)

Is this possible without hardcoding the addresses inside the linker script for `application.elf` (and needing to change them whenever I change something in the bootloader)?

The `INPUT` linker-script command only accepts object files, so that command is not useful, and I can't find any other useful command there.

In general, it feels like I'm trying to solve this problem with the wrong tools.

Comment: "I would like to be able to load symbols from an existing (.elf-)binary for usage in a linker script" -- have you considered generating the linker script dynamically at build time?

Comment: Do you convert these ELF executables to flat binary files, or are the ELF exectuables loaded into memory with something that understand ELF?

Comment: An option that may work for you and is simpler would be to use LD `-R filename` option that allows you to read symbols (and allow the linker to use them) from an ELF file without that file being output into the resulting binary. But `-R` would only work in this case if `filename` is an ELF executable and not an actual binary. Bianry files have all the symbol data removed of course.

Comment: Yes, these are both elf files, and -R looks really promising and much like what I need. Can I somehow specify which symbols I want to import? Or will it only use these symbols for symbols that are missing from the main compilation? Because `bootloader.elf` does not only contain the symbols I want to reference, but also many others, like `main`, which I want to declare independently in `application.elf`.

Comment: Nice, I've got it working. I now convert the bootloader-binary into a "header"-binary, with `ld -r -R bootloader.elf -o bootloader-interface.elf --retain-symbols-file to-export.txt`, and then I can easily import the symbols into the main link command with `ld -o application.elf obj1.o obj2.o bootloader-interface.elf` Do you want to write this as answer or shall I?

Comment: Please feel free to self answer! Glad you got it going! I didn't answer right away because I wasn't tagged in your comments. I just happened to come back to yuor question to see if anythign changed and saw your comments 10-13 hours late. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ld` offers an option to load just the symbols of a binary to be able to reference them during linkage (thanks to @michael-petch for pointing me to this option):

```
-R filename
--just-symbols=filename
  Read symbol names and their addresses from filename, but do not relocate it
  or include it in the output.
```

Concretely, using `-r` to create intermediate linker files, one can use:

```
ld -r --just-symbols=bootloader.elf -o bootloader-interface.elf \
  --retain-symbols-file to-export.txt
```

to create an intermediate elf-file `bootloader-interface.elf`, that only contains the symbols listed in `to-export.txt` and does not contain any contents for the symbols, and then use that elf-file just like any other source during linkage.

In a linker script this file can be brought into the linkage with:

```
INPUT(path/to/bootloader-interface.elf);
```

Then all exported symbols can be used inside the linker script for `application.elf` and also consequently referenced from the object files for `application`.

Answer (score 1):

> As a primitive, I would like to be able to load symbols from an existing (.elf-)binary for usage in a linker script without including any payload data from the other binary, but that does not seem to be possible.

The way I would approach this is:

1. Link `bootloader.elf`
2. Run `readelf bootloader.elf` to extract symbol addresses, size, etc.
3. Feed this info into a trivial generator in Perl, Python, whatever, which will write a new `application.lds` linker script
4. Use the newly generated script to link `application.elf`.

All within your `Makefile`.

P.S. If extracting all the relevant info from `bootloader.elf` proves bothersome, write a simple `C` program to do that (using e.g. `libelf` to actually parse `bootloader.elf`). That program can then spit out the `application.lds` directly).

Comment: Yes, generating a linker script is definitely a good fallback approach, if the linker script language itself does not allow loading symbols. So for now I'm interested if loading symbols is possible within the linker script language itself, which does not seem to be a too far-fetched feature. If it isn't, this is definitely the way to go.